# C# not recognizing a string sent to powershell somehow

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to remove an email alias from a mailbox which is selected by the user.

```
string removeAlias = "Set-Mailbox \"" + userLabel.Text + "\" -EmailAddresses @{remove=\"" + textBox2.Text + "\"}";
```

However, this does not work and I am not getting any error. Also, the following code works to add an email alias:

```
string setAlias = "Set-Mailbox \"" + userLabel.Text + "\" -EmailAddresses @{add=\"" + alias + "\"}";
```

I still cant figure out why this does not work. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for any one facing such trouble. There was a whitespace in my alias string and so Powershell was not accepting it. I used the following to get rid of whitespaces:

selectedAlias = Regex.Replace(selectedAlias, "[\n\r\t]", "");